# how to build GoogleAnalytics for monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, google-analytics

I'm new here. How do i build   [GoogleAnalytics](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/GoogleAnalytics)  for MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0):

Clone the `monotouch-bindings` repository, go to the GoogleAnalytics folder, and type `make`. If you have all the right tools installed (you should if you can build a Xamarin.iOS app), this will generate the `GoogleAnalytics.dll` you need.